# primereact overlay components (dialog, sidebar) - inconsistent bug - Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, primereact

So we have a primereact components based app,
and the problem occurs when triggering the show of an overlay component
(usually a Dialog, but I've noticed it could also happen with Sidebar),

in a specific page that concerns with showing a table and the basic crud associated with it,
we show the form to create/update inside a Dialog,
when clicking the appropriate button the dialog shows..

only *sometimes* the dialog crashes and this error shows:
[image: chrome-console-error-log]

this have been happening for a very long time, and there were many attempts,
not even to fix it, but just to get the bug re-produced consistently.
couldnt do it...

of course tried finding a setState that could get stuck in a loop

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Without a Code Sandbox reproducer its impossible to tell what you problem is or how to help.

Comment: yeah.. thats a great part of the issue itself, as i cant seem to reproduce the bug consistenly even on the local full project...
even so, was hoping for some insights on how to approach this

Comment: OK that is interesting!  I have node advice to give on how to reproduce it. Sorry!